# Prime Number Correction (2 Arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, primes

So essentially what I am trying to do is use one array to populate prime numbers and output the result into a different array. I know I can simply print them out with 2 for loops and use a boolean statement to print the values out, but I really want to do it this way and figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
public class primeSum{

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] array = new int[100];
int[] result = new int[array.length];
int aLength = array.length;

for(int i = 2; i < aLength; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0 && i%3 == 0){
        break;
    }
    else{
        result[i] = i;
        System.out.println(i + " ");
     }

   }
 }
}
```

I simply want to add the primes to the result array and print them out.

Comment: What's the purpose of `array`? Why do you `break` when you hit 6? And what's your question?

Comment: my question is basically how I would add primes to the result array and print it out and array is basically to store 100 numbers, i could have used something like int max = 100 instead of array, I just wanted to use an array in this case, that's all.

Comment: But you're not storing anything in `array`. And there's nothing in your code that checks for prime numbers.

Comment: Also @shmosel you make a good point, that I am breaking it after 6 how do i fix that, how do i keep checking numbers?

Comment: Ahh i see what you're talking about, I simply had an array sized 100, I gotcha!

Comment: "_I simply want to add the primes to the result array and print them out._" The code you have already adds stuff to arrays and prints things so you should be able to do this no problem. Can you be more specific what issue you are having (besides the fact that this code has nothing to do with primes at all)?

Comment: I thought doing i%2 == 0 and i % 3 ==0 would eliminate all the numbers divisible by 2 and 3 (aka all non primes) and the rest of the numbers would be added to the result array. Once they are in the result array, I would simply print them out.

Comment: `eliminate all the numbers divisible by 2 and 3 (aka all non primes)` Maybe you should revisit what defines a prime number. Take for example the number 25. Your code checks if it is evenly divisible by 2 (it isn't) so flow goes to the else block and you add it to your `result` array. However, 25 IS NOT A PRIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one of java best practise is to write the first letter of the name of the class in uppercase (ex: `class PrimeSum`).
Here is a simple way to do what you want.

```
public class PrimeSum{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] array = new int[100];
  int[] result = new int[array.length];
  int aLength = array.length;

  for(int i = 2; i < aLength; i++){

    if(isPrime(i)){

    result[i] = i;

    System.out.println(i); // if you want you can avoid this instruction and active above "displayNonNullValueArray(result);"

 }
 } 

 //displayNonNullValueArray(result); you can also use this instruction to display your array "result"

}

// test if an integer is a prime number
static boolean isPrime(int m){

  for(int i=1; i<=m; i++){

      if(m%i==0 && i!=1 && i!=m){
         return false;
      }
  }

  return true;
   }

   //display an non-null values of an array
static void displayNonNullValueArray(int[] a){

 for(int val:a){

     if(val!=0){
         System.out.println(val);
     }
 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A prime number is a whole number greater than 1, whose only two whole-number factors are 1 and itself.

```
public class primeSum
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {        
       int[] array  = new int [100];
       int num =0;

       int[] result = new int[100];

       for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++)         
       {              
          int counter=0;      
          for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
      {
             if(i%num==0)
         {
        counter = counter + 1;
         }
      }
      if (counter ==2)
      {

        result[i] = i;
      } 
       }    

       for(int j=2; j<=array.length; j++){

         if(result[j] != 0){
             System.out.println(result[j]);
         }

     }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps